# ng-click stops working after the first use of $compile when using nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular modal directive that uses a helper/wrapper directive. This way I can always use the same wrapper and just load a different template where needed for different modal content.

**PROBLEM:** This snippet works, but only for the first life cycle of the modal. So I can fire the modal, close the modal and fire it again. But once the modal is open the second time none of the ng-click directives work. Any tips would be just super.

**Usage**

```
<button my-modal="views/login.html">Launch Login-specific Modal</button>
```

**Directive Module** (app.js)

```
angular.module('myModal',[])

.directive('modalWrapper', function(){
  return {
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'views/modal.html',
    controller: function($scope, $element){
      $scope.close = function(){
        $element.remove();
      };
      // NOTE: I use this array to showcase that ng-repeat still works the second time although ng-click stops functioning properly.
      $scope.others = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
    }
  }
})

.directive('myModal', function( $compile){

      function link(scope, element, attr){

      scope.partial = attr.myModal; // NOTE: Loads sub template via ng-include

      var ngModal = $compile('<div modal-wrapper></div>')(scope);

      element.on('click', function(){
        angular.element('body').append(ngModal);
      });

      scope.yo = function(){
        alert("Yo from inside template.");
      };

    }

    return {
      link: link,
      scope: {}
    }
});
```

**Templates**

modal.html

```
<div class="my-modal">
    <p>Modal Wrapper</p>
    <div ng-include="partial"></div>
  <button ng-click="close()">Close</button>
  <p>This just proves that other directives still work (ng-repeat), but ng-click does not.</p>
  <div ng-repeat="stuff in others">
    <p>{{stuff}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

login.html

```
<h1>Well hey there, I'm the login template.</h1>
<button ng-click="yo()">Say Yo</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are destroying the scope on which the `ng-click` is compiled.

When `scope.close()` is called, an `$element.remove()` occurs. This both removes the element from the DOM, and destroys the scope to which it is attached. This will result in your `ng-click` being de-registered.

Unfortunately (as of last time I checked), `element.detach()` also destroys scope, so your best bet is to compile and append the element to body only once. After this you can use `element.show()` and `element.hide()` to show and hide the modal. Alternatively you can recompile the modal each time you want to show it.

Comment: I'm fine with recompiling when I run the directive again, but I'm curious why the code above doesn't recompile.

Comment: In the code above, when you do `$element.remove()` the scope for `directive-wrapper` is destroyed and events etc are cleaned up. When you then append the modal back onto `body`, you are bringing back an element that is already disposed of.

Comment: While, I really would like to recreate it every time and I feel like showing/hiding is sort of hackish, it does in fact work. Thanks for your help and input @Andyrooger

Comment: This line should work for a complete recreation in the click event if you are having trouble: `angular.element('body').append($compile('<div modal-wrapper></div>')(scope));`